# Salvar Caminho da imagem no banco e chamar na View Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando salvar o caminho da imagem no banco, e depois chamar na view, porém, esta salvando o caminho fisíco inteiro. e na hora de chamar, não aparece a imagem.

Minha Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
        {
            ImagensBlog imagem = new ImagensBlog();
            var path = "";
            if (file != null)
            {
                foreach (var arquivo in file)
                {
                    if (arquivo.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        if (Path.GetExtension(arquivo.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg"
                          || Path.GetExtension(arquivo.FileName).ToLower() == ".png"
                              || Path.GetExtension(arquivo.FileName).ToLower() == ".gif"
                          || Path.GetExtension(arquivo.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg")
                        {

                            path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/Blog"), arquivo.FileName);
                            arquivo.SaveAs(path);
                            ImagensBlog img = new ImagensBlog();
                            img.UrlDaImagem = path;
                            img.DataSalvamento = DateTime.Now;
                            ViewBag.UploadSuccess = true;
                            imagem.Salvar(img);
                            //db.ImagensBlogs.Add(img);
                        }
                    }


                }
                ViewBag.msg = "Salvo Com Suceso";
                return View();
            }

            ViewBag.msg = "Não foi possivel";
            return View();
        }
```

gostaria que salvasse apenas o caminho assim: `~/Imagens/Blog/NomedaImagem.Extensão`
porém ta salvando assim:

```
C:\Users\MeuUsuario\source\repos\E-Commerce\E-Commerce\Imagens\Blog_MG_9355.jpg
```

Minha View:

```
@model IEnumerable<E_Commerce.Models.Loja.ImagensBlog>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UrlDaImagem)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataSalvamento)
        </th>
        <th>
           Imagem
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrlDaImagem)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataSalvamento)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="@item.UrlDaImagem" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retire o

```
Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(
```

e use o

```
"~/Imagens/Blog/" + arquivo.FileName;
```

O uso do HttpContext.Server.MapPath, faz com que seja recuperado o caminho físico do seu arquivo e o  Path.Combine combina a raiz do caminho físico com o restante do caminho.

Veja mais [AQUI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2) e [AQUI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.7.2)